# Exposing passwords in django

Tags: python, django

For a git repository that is shared with others, is it a vulnerability to expose your database password in the `settings.py` file? (My initial thought was no, since you still need the ssh password.)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on who has read access to the repository, but it's generally a good idea not to put passwords into version control. It's probably better to put it in a seperate file like `password.py` with only the password in it, like this:

```
password = 'asdasd'
```

and `import` or `execfile` this in your `settings.py`. You can then add the `password.py` to your [`.gitignore`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore).

Answer (score 2):

That assumes your database is only accessible from one specific host, and even then, why would you want to give a potential attacker another piece of information?  Suppose you deploy this to a shared host and I have an account on there, I could connect to your database just by logging into my account on that box.

Also, depending on who you are writing this for and what kind of auditing they need to go through (PCI, state audits, etc), this might just not be allowed.

I would try to find a way around checking in the password.